# Thymeleaf not recognizing Lombok getters and setters

Tags: java, intellij-idea, spring-boot, thymeleaf, lombok

Lombok plugin is installed. Using IntelliJ 15. Structure of model shows the getters and setters but I get the following error from Thymeleaf.

Error:

> Invalid property 'postTitle' of bean class [com.blog.domain.Post]: Bean property 'postTitle' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?

The model:

```
@Entity
public @Data class Post {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @NotEmpty
    private String postTitle;

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne
    private Author postAuthor;

    @NotNull
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date postDate;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "TEXT")
    private String postTeaser;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "TEXT")
    private String postBody;

}
```

The controller method that loads the form:

```
@GetMapping("/create")
public String postForm(Post post, Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("authors", authorService.getAllAuthors());
    return "postform";
}
```

The field where error occurs:

```
<input id="postTitle" type="text" th:field="*{postTitle}" />
```

Any ideas where I'm going wrong? Adding the getters and setters manually solves the problem. What is lombok doing here that is breaking it?

Comment: show your Controller code? cos I can't reproduce it, everything works just fine on my machine

Comment: Added the controller method to original post.

Comment: and your input is in the form, right? Just for the testing purposes I would add simple text field `<p th:text="'postTitle: ' + ${post.postTitle}" ></p>` and checked with `model.addAttribute("post", new Post());` in controller get method. It's weird tho. don't you have any unusual lombok configs by any chance?

Comment: Yeah it's in the form. Nothing unusual other than that I'm using Boot version 1.4.0 M3. Could this be the reason?

Comment: Dunno, but I tested on 1.3.5 version. Maybe worth trying to downgrade

Comment: there is a related issue in the IDEA issue tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-132738 (if auto-complete works with other stuff it may not be related)

Comment: @Lithicas have you resolved that issue?

Comment: @Enigo Error still occurs. I opted out of using Lombok for this project for now. I'll assume that it's either an IntelliJ issue or an issue with my Spring Boot version.

Comment: I have the same problem using Intellij 16.1 + Spring Boot 1.3.6 + spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf + lombok 1.16.8. The project compiles and runs fine. I can call getter and setter methods in .java files with no issue. However I am unable to access the field in a Thymeleaf template.

Comment: Actually, I just realized I my controller was extending WebMvcConfigurerAdapter and I was returning "redirect:/results". After changed it back to returning just "results" it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this using a boolean named "isEnabled". Renaming it to "enabled" worked. Not sure about the reason for this though.

Comment: Please, add an example of your solution if possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting the Post object from somewhere make sure it is initialised as a normal class not as Optional one.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).